# Execute windows phone application to software application in visual studio 2013?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013

I have developed windows phone 8 apps using windows phone-8-SDk.  I want to create executable(.exe/msi) file for my windows 8 phone application.   How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to create an EXE of your WP8 to run somewhere other than actually on a real WP8 physical device, you can't.  The only platform that can execute WP8 code is a WP8 device or emulator.

Comment: OK.Then ,How to do make Application for this?